# awk: pre-processing of the data in the multi-column data

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I am working on the vizualisation of the data provided in the following multi-column format:

```
| Run on Thu Oct 20 14:59:37 2022
|| GB non-polar solvation energies calculated with gbsa=2
idecomp = 1: Per-residue decomp adding 1-4 interactions to Internal.
Energy Decomposition Analysis (All units kcal/mol): Generalized Born solvent

DELTAS:
Total Energy Decomposition:
Residue |  Location |       Internal      |    van der Waals    |    Electrostatic    |   Polar Solvation   |    Non-Polar Solv.  |       TOTAL
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SER   1 | R SER   1 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.092 +/-  0.012 |    0.092 +/-  0.012 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.000 +/-  0.001
GLY   2 | R GLY   2 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.001 +/-  0.001 |   -0.001 +/-  0.001 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.000 +/-  0.001
PHE   3 | R PHE   3 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.003 +/-  0.001 |    0.004 +/-  0.001 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.000 +/-  0.001
ARG   4 | R ARG   4 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.160 +/-  0.025 |    0.164 +/-  0.025 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.003 +/-  0.001
LYS   5 | R LYS   5 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.211 +/-  0.038 |    0.230 +/-  0.038 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.019 +/-  0.004
MET   6 | R MET   6 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.006 +/-  0.003 |    0.010 +/-  0.003 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.004 +/-  0.001
ALA   7 | R ALA   7 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.019 +/-  0.003 |    0.023 +/-  0.003 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.003 +/-  0.001
```

I need to reduce this multi-column's to two column format for the subsequent ploting of the bar graph. In particularly I need to take only the 1st and last columns with some modifications of the initial data.

1. in the indexes from the first (Residue) column all spaces should be substituted to "_" so `SER   1` should become `SER_1`.
2. from the last (TOTAL) column the info regarding the error should be eliminated so  `0.000 +/-  0.001` should become `0.000` etc..

I've tried to use AWK to select these two columns and additionally apply the condition on the second column. However, owing to the presence of the error info the conditions could not be applied.

```
awk -F "|"  '
    BEGIN {
        print "@TYPE bar"
    }
    NR > 9 && $8 > 0.005 { print $1, $8 }
' $file > output_data.dat
```

which gives me something like this:

```
@TYPE bar
SER   1      0.000 +/-  0.001
GLY   2      0.000 +/-  0.001
PHE   3      0.000 +/-  0.001
ARG   4      0.003 +/-  0.001
LYS   5      0.019 +/-  0.004
MET   6      0.004 +/-  0.001
ALA   7      0.003 +/-  0.001
PHE   8      0.001 +/-  0.001
PRO   9      0.004 +/-  0.001
SER  10     -0.007 +/-  0.002
GLY  11      0.001 +/-  0.001
LYS  12      0.006 +/-  0.002
VAL  13     -0.010 +/-  0.009
GLU  14      0.002 +/-  0.005
GLY  15      0.004 +/-  0.002
CYS  16     -0.006 +/-  0.005
MET  17      0.023 +/-  0.010
VAL  18     -0.058 +/-  0.018
```

while the expected output would be:

```
@TYPE bar
SER_1      0.000
GLY_2      0.000
PHE_3      0.000
ARG_4      0.003
LYS_5      0.019
...
VAL_18     -0.058
```

How could I additionally modify format of the data in the selected columns ?

Comment: i've just added it to the initial message!

Comment: why are `SER_1`, `GLY_2`, `PHE_3` and `ARG_4` in the output since the last column for these rows is not greater than `0.005` (`$8 > 0.005`)?

Comment: sorry this was ouput without the applied condition since the question was mainly related to the manipulation of the inout fields.. i am going to test your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a bit more parsing/manipulation of the input fields, eg:

```
awk -F'|' '
BEGIN { print "@TYPE bar" }
NF==8 { gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$1)        # strip leading/trailing spaces from 1st field
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"_",$1)                      # convert all contiguous spaces to a single '_'

        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$8)        # strip leading/trailing spaces from 8th field
        split($8,a,"[[:space:]]")                        # split 8th field on white space

        if (a[1]+0 == a[1] && a[1] > 0.005)              # if 1st sub-field is numeric and > 0.005 then ... 
           print $1,a[1]                                 # print to stdout
      }
' data
```

**NOTES:**

- `a[1]+0 == a[1]` - shorthand method of testing if `a[1]` is numeric (ie, eliminates the header line where `a[1]=="TOTAL"`)
- `a[1] > 0.005` - from OP's current `awk` code, though this comparison does not appear to have been applied in OP's expected output; remove this comparison if all lines should be displayed

This generates:

```
@TYPE bar
LYS_5 0.019
```

If we remove the comparison (`&& a[1] > 0.005`) this generates:

```
@TYPE bar
SER_1 0.000
GLY_2 0.000
PHE_3 0.000
ARG_4 0.003
LYS_5 0.019
MET_6 0.004
ALA_7 0.003
```

Comment: I gotcha, thank you very much for this elegant solution! Cheers

Comment: updated, just a quick answer for the pre-processing: would it be possible additionally via your awk script to change the format of the output values from the 8th column from x.xxx just to x.x (just one number after the dot) ?

Comment: @JamesStarlight  you could replace `print $1,a[1]` with `printf "%s %.1f\n",$1,a[1]`;  for this particualr set of data this will print `0.0` for *all* of the output lines